# Term aggregation on filtered array items

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to aggregate on term that are inside an array but I am only interested in some of the array item. I made up a simplified example. Basically I want to aggregate on `Type.string` if `Type.field` is `valid`.

```
POST so/question
{
  "Type": [
    [
      {
        "field": "invalid",
        "string": "A"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "field": "valid",
        "string": "B"
      }
    ]
  ]
}

GET /so/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "xxx": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "Type.field": "valid"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "yyy": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "Type.string.keyword",
            "min_doc_count": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The agregation result has 2 keys whereas I only need the "B" key.

```
"aggregations": {
  "xxx": {
    "doc_count": 1,
    "yyy": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "A",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "B",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to aggregate on array items which match the filter?
Unfortunately I can't change the data format which would be the obvious solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless, the documents are of [Nested Type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html), I don't think its possible with simple array types because of the way [Elasticsearch Flattens](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#_how_arrays_of_objects_are_flattened) the objects and stores them.

Querying anything on these flattened objects will give you completely unexpected results.

Now I've come up with the below query, making use of [Terms Aggregation using Script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script) works perfectly fine for the document you've mentioned in the question

```
POST so/_search
{

  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "xxx": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "Type.field": "valid"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "yyy": {
          "terms": {
            "script": { 
              "source": """
                  int size = doc['Type.string.keyword'].values.length;
                  for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
                    String myString = doc['Type.string.keyword'][i];
                    if(myString.equals("B") && doc['Type.field.keyword'][i].equals("valid")){
                      return myString;
                    }
                  }""",
              "lang": "painless"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However if you ingest the below document, you see that the aggregation response would be completely different. That is because, array types doesn't store each `Type.field` value and `Type.string` value in an `ith` location in their respective arrays.

```
POST so/question/2
{
  "Type": [
    [
      {
        "field": "valid",
        "string": "A"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "field": "invalid",
        "string": "B"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Notice even the below simple [Bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query wouldn't work as expected and ends up displaying both the documents.

```
POST so/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "Type.field.keyword": "valid" }},
        { "match": { "Type.string.keyword": "B" }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I ended up using nested type which is the best option. Thanks for pointing out that feature.